# What is the proj4js projection code for the Gall-Peters Projection?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, proj4js

Does the Proj4JS library support the Gall-Peters projection? I can't seem to find a projection acronym for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you are looking for is "cea" for Cylindrical Equal Area.

The actual definition will be:

```
"+proj=cea +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +lat_ts=45 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
```

Change the value of lat_ts to 44.138 for the strict Peter projection, although as your title implies, the Gall and Peters projections are virtually the same (I won't get into *that * political argument, thank you!).

Some prefer the Behrman which is similar but with a lat_ts of 30. This produces less distortion of the equatorial regions (something Peters was claiming he was trying to fix!) .

Comment: How does that compare with the Proj4JS format from:
  http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6838/

They are slightly different values.

Comment: 6838 appears to use the CEA projection, but as far as I can tell, it is not the Gall-Peters projection. It looks like it is used for a specific need because the meridian (longitude 0) is significantly different too.