# how I can get the geoJson file for gall-peters world map for react leaflet

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, geojson, react-leaflet, world-map

How to get gall-peter geojson or how to make that

I have used react leaflet for make an interactive map using geojson data, its working well but now i need to change the map projection to gall-peters map, so i need the geojson for the particular map projection,
how can i get that. Now i am using mercator map geojson data

Answer (score 0):

First, let's forget about react and react-leaflet right now.  Let's just focus on what you're trying to do with leaflet.  You need to change the projection / CRS that your map is using.  To create a map with a less common projection, you can use the leaflet plugin [Proj4Leaflet](https://kartena.github.io/Proj4Leaflet/).  You'll also need the projection definition.  For gall-peters, which has the projection code ["cea" (Cylindrical Equal Area)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4229007/12010984), you can find the Proj4 code to use with Proj4Leaflet [here](https://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6838/).  Putting it alltogether to create a map in that projection:

```js
import "proj4leaflet";

const resolutions = Array.from({ length: 15 })
  .map((_, i) => (i + 200) ** 2)
  .reverse();

// Define your projection
var crs = new L.Proj.CRS(
  "SR-ORG:6838",
  "+proj=cea +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +lat_ts=45 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs",
  {
    resolutions,
    origin: [0, 0]
  }
);

var map = L.map("leafletMapid", { crs, ...otherOptions });
```

Now, adding GeoJSON to the map will automatically be in that projection.  Note the `resolutions` variable, which needs some fine tuning to get things working properly.

### [Vanilla Leaflet Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gall-peters-geojson-8fctw)

Getting this to work in react-leaflet is just a matter of creating that projection and giving it to the `MapContainer`:

```
const Map = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    // fetch geojson on mount and save to state
    fetch("geojsonurl")
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((r) => setData(r));
  }, []);

  return (
    <MapContainer 
      {...mapOptions} 
      crs={crs} // defined in the same way as above
    >
      {data && <GeoJSON data={data} />}
    </MapContainer>
  );
};
```

### [Working react-leaflet codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gall-peters-react-leaflet-kfyh6)

As you can see, you have a react-leaflet map with GeoJSON in your desired projection.

Note that if you want to put a tilelayer under it that also follows this projection, that a whole other story.  You can check out the docs on [Proj4Leaflet](https://kartena.github.io/Proj4Leaflet/) for more on how to do that.

I was getting some `Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, -130.1624500907549)` error, though it didn't seem to effect the map.  I'm 100% sure it has to do with the way proj4leaflet is using the `resolutions`, so you'll have to play with that.  For those sandboxes, I disabled the error overlay with some css on `iframe`.

Comment: I done the projection as per you said the same issue "NaN" is came, I will do the rejection of the error overlay.. lets look and Thanks dude

Comment: If this answer was what you were looking for, please mark it as the answer, and give it an upvote if it was helpful